# Is it possible to generate Jmeter Dashboard Report using a XML?

Tags: xml, jmeter, dashboard

I'm having problems to generate report in Jmeter using the csv file, because it looks like it does not return all data I need (for example, failure message for JSON response). So, I exported a XML in View Results Tree, and in this XML I have all the failure messages.

My question, is this a way to generate a Jmeter Dashboard/Report with this XML?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) it's not possible, [documentation on the HTML Reporting Dashboard says](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]

If you want both request and response data and the possibility to generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard you will need to add a Listener, i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured to save request and response data into a **separate file**

[image]

So you will have:

- [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in CSV format and it will be possible to generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard from it
- XML results file from the Simple Data Writer with all the request and response details.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)